# How to make page adaptive in tailwind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

I have a figma design template with login form in pixels:

```
.form { 
  position: relative;
  width: 632px;
  height: 1280px;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-template: 50% 50%
}

<div class="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div><label>Name</labe><input></div>
        <div><label>Second Name</labe><input></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I need to set max width to `.form` to avoid input form resizing by full page. Now it is `width: 632px;` in design (vertical form).

How to rewrirte this on tailwind?
After reading doc in section [container](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container) I did not find width for `width: 632px;`. There are only:

```
container   None    width: 100%;
sm (640px)  max-width: 640px;
md (768px)  max-width: 768px;
lg (1024px) max-width: 1024px;
xl (1280px) max-width: 1280px;
2xl (1536px)    max-width: 1536px;
```

So, how to make form adaptive using tailwind?

Comment: You don't _have_ to use the tailwind classes and just use standard CSS for cases like this, or define your own class set. See the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration) for more context.

Comment: Okay, I can determice own classed but how integrate it in tailwind to use as kit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override("configure") default spacing you posted for the container in your tailwind configuration file.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing#overriding-the-default-spacing-scale

To completely "override", you can modify `theme.spacing`.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    spacing: {
      sm: '634px',
      md: '...',
      lg: '...',
      xl: '...',
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to "[extend](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing#extending-the-default-spacing-scale)" (or override only the ones you want to, in your case, `sm`) you can change `theme.extend.spacing` as shown below.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
    spacing: {
      sm: '634px'
    }
  }
}
```

This will only change `sm:` to `634px` while leaving others (`md`, `lg`, etc) intact (as Tailwind CSS defined).

Comment: I still can not get how to be if I have custom design from Figma. It has customized buttons (padding,sizes, etc). There is no predefined properties in Tailwind. Does it mean I must define own schma color, padding, sizes etc? Why then I have to use Tailwind if I do it by handmade from scratch?

Could you share a good example how to apply Tailwind for custom design?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a tool to convert Figma CSS to Tailwind utilities. You'd need to "extend" or "override" from the theme (padding/margin/colors, etc) to match those in Figma. My [website](https://sung.codes) is built based on Material Design. And you can check the config [here](https://gist.github.com/dance2die/5ff2d2d3c6c77883df328fcd57baa60c) (full source not available due to sensitive info).